# What is the meaning of "his path beaten out in the turf"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

*Suddenly the darkness about him glowed; a furnace fire had shot up on the mountain, and for a moment the little world of the woodside and the steep hill shone in a pale light, and he thought he saw his path beaten out in the turf before him.*

It's from Arthur Machen's Hill of Dreams. I didn't quite understand what it means to "his path beaten out in the turf"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He looked at the turf (grass) in front of him, and thought he could see it flattened, as if by feet which had passed before, in a way which suggested a trail or path that he should follow.

Comment: Just as an addendum: this is formed off the expression: beaten path.